# How can I use gettext in vala?

Tags: gettext, vala

When I try to use gettext in vala I get not errors or warnings from vala but I get the following error from the c compiler:

```
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n-lib.h:29:2: error: #error You must define GETTEXT_PACKAGE before including gi18n-lib.h. Did you forget to include config.h?
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this problem I had to both add `-X -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE="..."` to the valac command and add `const string GETTEXT_PACKAGE = "...";` to the top of my source file.

If I don't add that to the top of my source file, I get lots of `undeclared (first use in this function)` errors from the C compiler for some reason.

I do, however, get a warning from the C compiler for redefining GETTEXT_PACKAGE.

Comment: To avoid the dupplicate GETTEXT_PACKAGE values, you may use `[CCode(cname="GETTEXT_PACKAGE")]
extern const string GETTEXT_PACKAGE;` instead of `const string GETTEXT_PACKAGE = "...";`.

Comment: Or just: `extern const string GETTEXT_PACKAGE;` I believe it's sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most common solution is to just pass -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE="..." to the C compiler (if you're just relying on valac to invoke it, pass -X -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE="..." to valac).

Answer (score 2):

This can help: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=618931